# How to show the discount percentage in actual in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to show the discount percentage in actual?

I have installed the **YITH wooCommerce badge management** plugin. but the discount % comes in round figure 50%

I want to show the actual discount % like this one `49.75`

Regular = `$8.50` 
Sale = `4.27` 
Discount in % `49.75`

Kindly someone guide me on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

add this snippet to your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_displayed_sale_price_html', 10, 2 );
function change_displayed_sale_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    // Only on sale products on frontend and excluding min/max price on variable products.
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && ! is_admin() && ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // Get product prices
        $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Regular price
        $sale_price    = (float) $product->get_price(); // Active price (the  "Sale price" when on-sale)

        // "Saving price" calculation and formatting.
        $saving_price = wc_price( $regular_price - $sale_price );

        // "Saving Percentage" calculation and formatting.
        $precision         = 1; // Max number of decimals
        $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';

        // Append to the formated html price.
        $price .= sprintf( __( '<p class="saved-sale">Save: %1$s <em>(%2$s)</em></p>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_price, $saving_percentage );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

You're ready. Enjoy!

Comment: I have applied your given code to a function.php file and it is not working.

Comment: I have it apply in two installations and it worked like a charm. Can you please tell me whats snippet produces in your case? Have you apply this snippet in the end of your functions.php? WP Version and theme?

Comment: Apply tour snippet and disable YITH Badge Plugin as a test

Comment: WordPress version 6.1.1
Theme: Custom